# Targeting New Relic to run only on 1 (of 3) app servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic

Our medium-sized rails app runs (in production) on three servers.  We've just finished a trial period, using New Relic as a gem.  During the trial period we tracked all three servers, but to continue with a subscription we only need (and only have the budget) to track app1.

So we need to **disable new relic on app2 and app3**.  In communication with their customer service I'm told this is possible and have been directed to the last entry on [this page](https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/ruby-agent-installation#Uninstalling_Gem) but I can't quite figure out how this helps me to disable new relic tracking on the other two servers, in particular because there's no newrelic_rpm mentioned in environment.rb - it's a gem, after all, and is therefore only mentioned in the Gemfile.

There is a `agent_enabled` boolean option in newrelic.yml which I thought we could set on a per-server basis, but I don't know how to do this.  Is there a way to find out which server we're on in rails, similar to the RAILS_ENV variable?

Comment: What are you using for deployments? capistrano?

Comment: Yep, via the capper gem.  We have a monitor in our capfile that notifies new relic when we deploy, otherwise everything is configured via the gem and newrelic.yml

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `newrelic.yml` file is rendered with ERB before the agent reads the config values. So you can do this:

```
monitor_mode: <%= 'app1' == Socket.gethostname ? 'true' : 'false' %>
```

That will enable the agent reporting to New Relic only for that one host.

Comment: This would be fantastic if it worked but it has disabled tracking on all servers, including app1.  How/where exactly is the ERB rendering taking place?

Comment: I should have noticed that too...stupid HAML making me forget things!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest linking `newrelic.yml` only on the server where it is needed. To make this happen remove `config/newrelic.yml` from you repository completely and put in into the `shared` directory in your servers instead.

Then link this file only for a certain role in capistrano again into `config/newrelic.yml`. You may introduce a new role that only contains your app1 server.

The new relic gem is build fail-safe. So it's just disabled in that case.

Comment: Removing config/newrelic.yml altogether makes newrelic_rpm throw an error every time it is loaded, which gets pretty tiresome in development.  Otherwise this would be a great solution.  Our current plan is to have two additional files, newrelic_disabled/_enabled.yml, and to overwrite newrelic.yml with these on deploy.

Comment: You mean a warning right? If you ignore that file via git an put on there in you development copy you would also get around the warning.

Comment: Yep, a warning, not an error, sorry.  That's a cool trick! I'll definitely bear it in mind for the future, I'm always surprised to remember that files can exist _outside_ of the git repo as well :) In this case we'll stick with our deploy method to avoid having to transfer files between the team the old-fashioned way tho, it might become a headache later. Thanks very much for your help!